# Robot Framework, log failed tests in current run

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I'd like to get a comma separated list of failed tests for a Robot Framework run. I'm running the tests on Jenkins and have a job that can take a comma separated list of test names to run. I want to easily get that string so I can rerun failed tests after a fix has been deployed, without running the entire job again.

I've considered using a global variable to add ${TEST NAME} in test teardowns if the test has failed, logging the entire string in each suite teardown. I assume I could also parse the output xml in the Jenkinsfile somehow and just echo it to the console.

Is there a simple way of getting this done?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to parse the ouptut xml. There is a option in robot framework that will do this for you. Simply run with the option --rerunfailed. Here is the [documentation.](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#command-line-options-for-test-execution)

```
robot --rerunfailed original.xml --output rerun.xml tests
```

Comment: I already have that as an option in the Jenkins job, but I can't just run with --rerunfailed; the instance that job ran on is dead and long gone. To rerun failed tests in another job on a new virtual machine I'd need the second job to be able to access the output.xml of the first one. It looks like the files are stored somewhere and accessible through the Jenkins UI, but I'm not too keen on creating a Jenkins job that accesses that to read the output xml.

Comment: What did you plan on doing with your coma separated list? How is that any different form the xml file?

Comment: I already have a Jenkins job that takes test names as a parameter. If every test logs a list of failed tests I can copy that, edit however I want and run the tests